# What is the best practice to handle if true then run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, solid-principles

```js
function handleOrder(data) {
  if (data.payment_type === 'VISA') {
     handleVisaPayment()
  }

  if (data.payment_type === 'VISA') {
     handleMastercardPayment()
  }

  if (data.payment_type === 'PayPal') {
     handlePayPalPayment()
  }

  if (data.shipping === 'Express') {
     handleExpressShipping()
  }

  if (data.shipping === 'Standard') {
     handleStandardShipping()
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this function especially by following best practices?

Comment: Create an object with methods named by the credit cards, and just check the type of `data.payment_type` in that object is a function, and then call that function.

Comment: Create a mapper object  `const mapper = {
        'VISA': handleVisaPayment,
        'MasterCard': handleMastercardPayment,
        'PayPal': handlePayPalPayment
      }` and then call the specific function based on shipping value: `mapper[data.shipping]()`

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array data structure that will hold the value you want to compare and the function that you want to execute in that case. That will simplify your code and keep it manageable:

```
let allowedValues = [{
    "value": "VISA",
    "handler": handleVisaPayment
  },
  {
    "value": "PayPal",
    "handler": handlePayPalPayment
  },
  {
    "value": "Express",
    "handler": handleExpressShipping
  },
  {
    "value": "Standard",
    "handler": handleStandardShipping
  }
]

function handleOrder(data) {
  let matchedOrder = allowedValues.find(({
    value
  }) => value === data.payment_type);
  if (matchedOrder) {
    matchedOrder.handler();
  }
}
```

You can even create a object mapping for those values and operations:

```
let allowedValues = {
  "VISA": handleVisaPayment,
  "PayPal": handlePayPalPayment,
  "Express": handleExpressShipping,
  "Standard": handleStandardShipping
}

function handleOrder(data) {
  if (allowedValues[data.payment_type]) {
    allowedValues[data.payment_type]();
  }
}
```

Comment: why an array not an object `{Value: handler}`?

Comment: @AZ_ yes we can

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are executing the same IF statement twice in a row.

```
if (data.payment_type === 'VISA') {
    handleVisaPayment
}

if (data.payment_type === 'VISA') {
    handleMastercardPayment
}
```

I imagine it would be more logical if your second IF statement was like this:

```
if (data.payment_type === 'Mastercard') {
    handleMastercardPayment
}
```

This looks like a simple copy-paste mistake, but I think it's worth pointing out.

Secondly, you might want to reorganize your code using a switch statement.
Ex:

```
switch (data.payment_type) {
  case 'VISA':
    handleVisaPayment
    break;
  case 'Mastercard':
    handleMastercardPayment
    break;
  case 'PayPal':
    handlePayPalPayment
    break;
}

switch (data.shipping) {
  case 'Express':
    handleExpressShipping
    break;
  case 'Standard':
    handleStandardShipping
    break;
}
```

This should make your code easier to read/maintain/add new features in the future.
Again, I know it was specified to avoid using switch, but it does look like the most simple solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give some building blocks to go further, as others have mentioned use mapping to resolve the functions you need.

```js
const data = {
  shipping: 'Standard',
  payment_type: 'VISA',
}

const handleVisaPayment = () => console.log('handling visa payment')
const handleStandardShipping = () => console.log('handling standard shipping')

const orderHandlingMap = {
  'Standard': handleStandardShipping,
  'VISA': handleVisaPayment,
}

const handleOrder = data =>
  Object.values(data)
    .filter(element => orderHandlingMap[element])
    .map(handlerName => orderHandlingMap[handlerName]())

handleOrder(data)
```